# Elements in .less files in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any way other than manually open up files to do the search?

Some files are intutive but how are they structured?

I am looking for .brand class at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`brand` is now `navbar-brand` refer  [Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 v/s 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952571/how-has-twitter-bootstrap-3-changed-over-version-2-3-2).  its in `navbar.less`.

`theme.less` is styled as per 2.3.2. Its standalone.

`type.less` contains `p, h1-6, ul,ol,  table - dt, dd, address, strong, abbr, .lead, q`.

`grid.less` contains the `col-1g-` etc column details. it defines the number of grids and column width etc.

`scaffolding.less` contains `html, body, a, hr, img, input textarea select button, img, :hover`

`variables.less` contains all variables used as values elsewhere & `mixin.less` contains mixins.

`dropdown.less, buttons.less, navbar.less` etc are topical on each subject.

`bootstrap.less` contains import statements only.
`forms.less` for form classes like `form-controls`